# How much user traffic/day each heroku dyno should attend?

Tags: heroku

I'm thinking about launching an web app with heroku but I have no idea to calculate the performance cost. According to their [website](https://www.heroku.com/pricing#support) 1 dyno to professional support is at least **$ 25 /month** gives a machine with "512MB or 1GB RAM".

If my website has a standard load assets and I have 1,000 people everyday access, how many "dynos" should be recommended to have a reasonable good speed for users?

Answer (score 0):

This will likely get shut down as it's not a 'programming' question. I'll try to answer quickly.

It all depends on how fast your page executes on the server, if it's slow then you run the risk of requests being timed out before they can be served by the app server. Adding more dyno's does not make your application faster though, changing the dyno type, standard-1x, 2x, PM, PL does as it makes more resources available however, slow code will always be slow code - throwing more resources at it is like a band-aid for a period of time.

In short, it's very application dependent both from a code point of view and traffic point of view - do those 1000 users arrive at the same time or are they spreadout?

Comment: Hi John Beynon, in my case the users will be spreadout along the day. I'm really worrying about the cost...

Comment: how much do you value your time? You could be building servers and having to manage them.

Comment: Hi John Beynon, I have no experience in this field and I know that heroku saves time to manage server. The core thing is: how much time it saves? And...how much it costs compared to others? We have Google app engine as an option too and I feel like walking in dark areas.